# How to create the custom drawable diagonal gradient

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to create the background gradient shown in attached image.

Currently I am using this xml, which is not giving the required effects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:endColor="#FF5C1E"
        android:startColor="#A300F3"
        android:type="linear"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

Please help me out here.
[image]

Comment: What is your problem?!

Comment: @miladsalimi the effect is not same like in above image.

Comment: @miladsalimi here what i am getting, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g6MJvNbjIH3elMk_RwUQJMG_YLw31e4E/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **should** use `radial` type of `gradient` for using this you **should** set `coordinates` **X** and **Y** as `centerX` and `centerY` and **finally**  for **radius** use this `gradientRadius` field.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:centerX="0.9"
        android:centerY="0.1"
        android:endColor="#FF5C1E"
        android:gradientRadius="1700"
        android:startColor="#A300F3"
        android:type="radial" />
</shape>
```